# How to add a scope and ApplicationURI to Azure AD Application Registration?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I have a powershell script that creates an azure ad app reg.  I've been able to create it, add ms graph permissions and also create a secret.  This is what I have so far:

```
$newapp = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName "mynewApp" -AvailableToOtherTenants $false
Write-Output $newapp
# add a certificate / client secret
$appCredentials = New-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationId $newapp.AppId -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate

$identifierUris = @()
$identifierUris += "api://$newapp.AppId"
$webAppUrl = "https://$functionAppName.azurewebsites.net"
# when you add a redirect URI Azure creates a "web" policy. 
$redirectUris = @()
$redirectUris += "$webAppUrl"   

Update-AzADApplication -ApplicationId $newapp.AppId -ReplyUrl $redirectUris | Out-Null
#Adds MS Graph User.Read permission
Add-AzADAppPermission -ApplicationId $newapp.AppId -ApiId "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" -PermissionId "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d"
```

But now I need to know how to create the application Uri as depicted below, and also how to create the scope.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **New-AzureADApplication** command with following parameters

- To add Identifier URI - Use *`-IdentifierUris`* parameter.
- To add Scope - Use  *`-Oauth2Permissions`* parameter.

```
New-AzureADApplication
[-AvailableToOtherTenants <Boolean>]
-DisplayName <String>
[-IdentifierUris <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]>]
[-Oauth2Permissions <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.OAuth2Permission]>]
[-ReplyUrls <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]>]
[-RequiredResourceAccess <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess]>]
```

For example you can create OAuth2Permission object like -

```
$scope = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.OAuth2Permission
$scope.Id = New-Guid
$scope.Value = "user_impersonation"
$scope.UserConsentDisplayName = "<value>"
$scope.UserConsentDescription = "<value>"
$scope.AdminConsentDisplayName = "<value>"
$scope.AdminConsentDescription = "<value>"
$scope.IsEnabled = $true
$scope.Type = "User"
```

Please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0) documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below command to create ApplicationId Uri ,

```
$newapp = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName "mynewApp" -AvailableToOtherTenants $false
$myappId=$newApp.AppId
Set-AzADApplication -ApplicationId $newApp.AppId -IdentifierUris "api://$myappId"
```

It may take little time to reflect in portal.

but to create scope , we may need to use azure ad module, and create a new id for user impersonation by enabling Oauth2permissions

please check if references can help

1. [SetupApplications ps1](https://github.com/robotechredmond/Azure-PowerShell-Snippets/blob/master/MicrosoftAzureServiceFabric-AADHelpers/AADTool/SetupApplications.ps1)
2. [azure-ad-app-registration-create-scopes](https://www.leogether.com/2022/01/azure-ad-app-registration-create-scopes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem with Azure Application Registration scopes. Here is a   simplest solution I have with Az Powershell:

```
$app = Get-AzAdApplication -ApplicationId "app_guid_here"

$permissionScope = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Powershell.Cmdlets.Resources.MSGraph.Models.ApiV10.MicrosoftGraphPermissionScope
$permissionScope.Id = New-Guid
$permissionScope.AdminConsentDescription = "text_here"
$permissionScope.AdminConsentDisplayName = "text_here"
$permissionScope.IsEnabled = $true
$permissionScope.Type = "Admin" #Or "User"
$permissionScope.UserConsentDescription = "text_here"
$permissionScope.UserConsentDisplayName = "text_here"
$permissionScope.Value = "user_impersonation"

$api = $app.Api
$api.Oauth2PermissionScope = $permissionScope

Update-AzADApplication -ApplicationId $appId -Api $api
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).